# Extract text from the html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have html as follows

```html
<div class="chart-component-header">
  <div class="template-block-header" contenteditable="false"><span><span class="collapse-icon open" data-action="collapse" title="Collapse section" contenteditable="false"></span><span class="template-block-title" contenteditable="false">Allergies</span></span>
    <ul class="template-block-toolbar">
      <li><span class="up up-icon grayOut" data-action="up" title="Move up" contenteditable="false"></span></li>
      <li><span class="down down-icon grayOut" data-action="down" title="Move down" contenteditable="false"></span></li>
      <li><span class="delete delete-icon" data-action="delete" title="Delete" contenteditable="false"></span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract Allergies from the span using jQuery or JS.
While I was using

```
$(this).text();
```

It was returning AllergiesAllergies

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. Assuming that `this` is the parent element of the html block it works as expected because there are two elements with the text `Allergies`

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Why the snippet and not a code block?

Comment: @Andreas, snippet have option to tidy the code and if anyone wants to answer this question then it will be easy "Copy snippet to Answer" option, otherwise code block is also an option but i choose snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this you can get the actual header value which you want

JQUERY

```
$("div.chart-component-body span.section-header").html();
```

JS

```
document.querySelector(".chart-component-body .section-header").innerHTML;
```

Comment: Why do you think OP wants the _"actual header value"_ and not the `.section-header`?